XRDP stopped working
My Ubuntu Desktop 22.04.4 LTS lost its XRDP access and I'm unable to figure out how to solve it. XRDP service is running, no errors in XRDP logs.
netstat -an | grep "LISTEN " | grep ":3389" 
tcp6       0      0 :::3389                 :::*                    LISTEN

All looks fine locally for the XRDP. The UFW is off. I think iptables are blocking it, but unable to figure out why. I've added an exception for 3389, but still no luck. The iptable list can be found here:
https://pastebin.com/yAK1b0Fj
Here are recent logs:
/var/log/xrdp.log
[20240423-16:35:44] [INFO ] address [0.0.0.0] port [3389] mode 1
[20240423-16:35:44] [INFO ] listening to port 3389 on 0.0.0.0
[20240423-16:35:44] [INFO ] xrdp_listen_pp done
[20240423-16:35:46] [INFO ] starting xrdp with pid 7789
[20240423-16:35:46] [INFO ] address [0.0.0.0] port [3389] mode 1
[20240423-16:35:46] [INFO ] listening to port 3389 on 0.0.0.0
[20240423-16:35:46] [INFO ] xrdp_listen_pp done
[20240423-16:36:52] [INFO ] Received termination signal, stopping the server accept new connections thread
[20240423-16:36:52] [INFO ] address [0.0.0.0] port [3389] mode 1
[20240423-16:36:52] [INFO ] listening to port 3389 on 0.0.0.0
[20240423-16:36:52] [INFO ] xrdp_listen_pp done
[20240423-16:36:54] [INFO ] starting xrdp with pid 7961
[20240423-16:36:54] [INFO ] address [0.0.0.0] port [3389] mode 1
[20240423-16:36:54] [INFO ] listening to port 3389 on 0.0.0.0
[20240423-16:36:54] [INFO ] xrdp_listen_pp done
[20240424-09:34:24] [INFO ] Received termination signal, stopping the server accept new connections thread
[20240424-09:38:39] [INFO ] address [0.0.0.0] port [3389] mode 1
[20240424-09:38:39] [INFO ] listening to port 3389 on 0.0.0.0
[20240424-09:38:39] [INFO ] xrdp_listen_pp done
[20240424-09:38:41] [INFO ] starting xrdp with pid 953
[20240424-09:38:41] [INFO ] address [0.0.0.0] port [3389] mode 1
[20240424-09:38:41] [INFO ] listening to port 3389 on 0.0.0.0
[20240424-09:38:41] [INFO ] xrdp_listen_pp done
[20240424-09:40:47] [INFO ] Received termination signal, stopping the server accept new connections thread
[20240424-09:51:10] [INFO ] address [0.0.0.0] port [3389] mode 1
[20240424-09:51:10] [INFO ] listening to port 3389 on 0.0.0.0
[20240424-09:51:10] [INFO ] xrdp_listen_pp done
[20240424-09:51:12] [INFO ] starting xrdp with pid 966
[20240424-09:51:12] [INFO ] address [0.0.0.0] port [3389] mode 1
[20240424-09:51:12] [INFO ] listening to port 3389 on 0.0.0.0
[20240424-09:51:12] [INFO ] xrdp_listen_pp done

~/.xsession-errors
Xsession: X session started for *** at Tue Apr 23 16:37:21 UTC 2024
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting DISPLAY=:3
localuser:*** being added to access control list
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting GTK_MODULES=gail:atk-bridge
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting QT_ACCESSIBILITY=1
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting VNCDESKTOP=Ubuntu-Desktop-***:3 (***)
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting LESSOPEN=| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting USER=***
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting SSH_CLIENT=85.255.26.116 17280 22
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XDG_SESSION_TYPE=x11
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting SHLVL=1
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting MOTD_SHOWN=pam
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting HOME=/home/***
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting SSH_TTY=/dev/pts/0
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting GTK_MODULES=gail:atk-bridge
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting IM_CONFIG_PHASE=1
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting LOGNAME=***
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting GTK_IM_MODULE=ibus
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XDG_SESSION_CLASS=user
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting TERM=xterm


/var/log/xrdp-sesman.log
[20240423-16:35:44] [INFO ] starting xrdp-sesman with pid 7779
[20240423-16:36:52] [INFO ] shutting down sesman 1
[20240423-16:36:52] [INFO ] starting xrdp-sesman with pid 7951
[20240424-09:34:25] [INFO ] shutting down sesman 1
[20240424-09:38:39] [INFO ] starting xrdp-sesman with pid 897
[20240424-09:40:47] [INFO ] shutting down sesman 1
[20240424-09:51:10] [INFO ] starting xrdp-sesman with pid 926

I've deployed and configured this machine in Azure. It was handed over to the developer to run Docker containers.
I'm testing RDP form Windows VM on the same LAN. Can ping it and SSH to it, but RDP is not working any more.
Help would be greatly appreciated. Please let me know if you would like any additional details.

When you try to RDP, does the connection fail immediately or do you get to the login screen, enter your credentials, then the session fails?
